# How to normalize speed of a projectile on Java 2D Game no matter what angle fired from

Tags: java, game-physics, graphics2d

I am writing a Java 2D Video game where I am firing bullets from a machine gun at passing aircraft.  I am able to alter the angle that I am firing from.  However, I have found the speed of the bullet seems to be effected by the angle from which it is fired.  If I fire the bullet vertically, it will travel much slower. If I fire it at 45 degrees, it will travel fast.  I imagine this might have to do with the alignment of the pixels.

Can someone direct me to some code or examples on how to handle this?  I would like the bullet to travel at the same speed no matter what the angle it has been fired from.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: polar coordinates, at least to start, so that the angle of the gun doesn't effect the velocity. This is little more than basic trig where the x-axis component is `r*cos(angle)` while the y-axis velocity is `r*sin(angle)`, where r is the scalar velocity.

Comment: @user1104028  " If I fire the bullet vertically, it will travel much slower"  .so it's depend on your code.post relevant codes.if you going to simulate real projectile speed of x axis never changed[almost same] if there is no forces like air resistance .but speed of y axis should be change with the time

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understood everything up to "polar coordinates, " :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: ha. Maybe I should clarify my muddy thoughts.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I learnt to do circle intersection today...trust me, it's my head that's spinning :P

Answer (score 0):

lets supose you are working with a cartesian coordinate system and your bullet has a "X" position and a "Y" position.

if your code-loop  is something like this when you fire it in vertical direction:

```
while(true){
    bullet.Y+=distanceUnit;
    Thread.sleep(timeUnit);
}
```

The bullet is traveling at "distanceUnit" pixels per timeUnit, but when you try fire at a 45° degrees angle if you do something like this:

```
while(true){
    bullet.x+=distanceUnit;
    bullet.y+=distanceUnit;
    Thread.sleep(timeUnit);
}
```

your bullet will be travelling at a root-square of(distance^2 + distance^2) pixels per timeUnit.

If and only if we are talking about 45° degrees angles that will be 1,414*distanceUnit per timeUnit speed.

So, because the bullet fired at a 45° degrees angle is 1,414 times faster than when fired vertically a rough solution is manually make it 1,414 times slower.

```
while(true){
   bullet.x+=Math.round(distanceUnit/1.414f);
   bullet.y+=Math.round(distanceUnit/1.414f);
   Thread.sleep(timeUnit);
}
```

But... if you want to fire at more degrees angles than vertically and 45° you need trignometrics.